# Logging which component is searching for which dll under which paths

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, unmanaged

An application that is trying to import unmanaged dlls via

```
[DllImport("Unmanaged.dll", EntryPoint = "UnmanagedMethod", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

and

```
LoadLibrary("AnotherUnmanaged.dll" )
```

keeps throwing

> HRESULT: 0x8007007E

exceptions.

The import works with absolute paths, i.e. the dlls exist and can be accessed. Since I can't use absolute paths in production, I need to find out which components need to know which additional include paths.

Is there a way to log all the info about which component is trying to find which dlls unter which paths?

Comment: You can place the dlls where the assembly of your app is located, that way no need of static paths

Comment: I tried that approach - but since the application uses a GUI and several other components, my assumption about where the assembly of my app is located must be wrong. Since the application consists of various components, I would prefer a more systematic approach.

Comment: You tried querying the assembly location through reflection and still that isn't helping you out, if I understand ?

Answer (score 1):

The Exception itself should contain the filename of the dll that isn't found, can you try logging that after catching with try{}catch?
Otherwise you can try inspecting your own dll with a tool like Dependencywalker or similar wich can find relations in dll's.

Edit:
The search paths are the same for default windows search paths (since unmanaged dll's get loaded with a call to LoadLibrary in windows). These are amongst others:

- Dll/exe directory
- Current directory
- Windows system folder: C:\windows\system32 or c:\windows\SysWOW64
- Windows folder
- The Path environment variable

More info about search paths: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa297182(v=vs.100)

Comment: Absolutely, the Exception contains the dll. Just not the search paths.